# Artifactory Pro 5.4.6 - Groovy plugin not executing on a schedule

Tags: artifactory

We have deployed a groovy script to the artifactory home plugin folders.
using the REST API we have loaded it successfully.
from the logs we can see that the load is successful.

> 2017-11-14 10:00:54,815 [http-nio-8081-exec-74] [INFO ] (o.a.a.p.GroovyRunnerImpl:244) - Loading script from 'purgeLibrary.groovy'.
>   2017-11-14 10:00:55,015 [http-nio-8081-exec-74] [INFO ] (o.a.a.p.e.ExecutePluginImpl:187) - Groovy execution 'purgeLibrary' has been successfully registered.
>   2017-11-14 10:00:55,023 [http-nio-8081-exec-74] [INFO ] (o.a.a.p.j.JobsPluginImpl:92) - Groovy job 'purgeOutdatedArtifacts' has been successfully scheduled to run.
>   2017-11-14 10:00:55,024 [http-nio-8081-exec-74] [INFO ] (o.a.a.p.GroovyRunnerImpl:296) - Script 'purgeLibrary' loaded.

and using the REST API again, we have manually executed the script purgeLibrary (again verified though log messages).

Job purgeOutdatedArtifacts and execution purgeLibrary are both wrappers around the same internal method, but job has default parms.

However, this 'job' never actually executes - again we can tell because there is nothing in the logs.
The relevant 'hook points' below...

```
executions {
   purgeLibrary() { params ->
    def dryRun = params["dryRun"] ? params["dryRun"][0] as boolean : false
    libraryPurge(dryRun) 
    }
 }
 jobs {
    // Finds ci/cd published Artifacts that have reached max daysToLive and purges them. Executes daily at 1am, server time.
    purgeOutdatedArtifacts(cron: "0 0 1 * * ?") {
        libraryPurge(true)  // default dryrun flag to true
    }
}
```

Now: all of this works in our test server - also same version of Artifactory. So my assumption is there is a configuration difference on the production server that is missing / not set correctly.

Any idea why the 'job' does not actually execute?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the job is actually running, but doing so at a different start time that equates to the value that was originally in the script.
I am still researching why it has not updated start time when we reloaded the script.

I am not deleting the question, in case this adds value to someone else